# Creating a cookie and setting the value

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to create a `cookie` and set the value depending on a column called `'User_ID'`. I then view the cookie in my browser and find that the value is:

```
SELECT+Student_ID+FROM+%60tblaccounts%60+WHERE+Email%3D%27test%27
```

I want the User_ID to be displayed i.e. 2 and not the command. How do I go about doing so? the code below is the code to set the cookie.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT Student_ID FROM `tblaccounts` WHERE Email='$username'"; 
$cookie_name2 = "userID";
$cookie_value2 = $sql2;
setcookie($cookie_name2, $cookie_value2);
```

Comment: You need to execute the SQL query? You're literally creating a string with the SQL query and store that string. Not sure what you expect to happen here?

Comment: I have recently come back to using sql and can not remember how to execute a query, could you help me with that?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I changed it so the line says   $result2 =  mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Student_ID FROM `tblaccounts` WHERE Email='$username'");

Comment: _"can not remember how to execute a query"_ - Then simply do a google search and try one of the hundreds of thousand examples you'll find. No reason to write _yet another_ example.

Comment: Ok, so you've changed it. What happens? Does it work? If you don't know how to go on from there, please check the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run mysql query and get value of student id.

**Example**

```
$result =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Student_ID FROM `tblaccounts` WHERE Email='$username'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$cookie_value2 = $row['Student_ID'];
$cookie_name2 = "userID";
setcookie($cookie_name2, $cookie_value2);
```

Comment: its not selecting the right User_ID where the value of the Email is the same in $username. instead, it is selecting the first User_ID

Comment: can you show me db image for particular row with column names.

Comment: It's working now. I had entered the wrong value of User_ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2 = "SELECT Student_ID FROM `tblaccounts` WHERE Email='$username'"; 
$res=$adb->pquery($sql2);
$cookie_name2 = "userID";
$cookie_value2 = $res;
setcookie($cookie_name2, $cookie_value2);
```

You need execute the query.`$res=$adb->pquery($sql2);`

Comment: Where did `$adb` come from?

Comment: I am using $adb object, It is only for reference, If you are using mysqli than write `$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database name"); mysqli_query($con,$sql2);` Please refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

Comment: Add that info in your answer. Just adding a magic variable and tell to OP to use it isn't particular helpful, since the OP might not have a clue what it is. Answers needs to be explicit.